# Sometime can not show data in ssrs report AX 2012

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, axapta

Each time open SSRS report in AX 2012 sometime can not show data. I try debug and use dialog show information, it's alway right...and I also try make new report but problem is still.

Answer (score 0):

Do you checked the Business Connector proxy settings in the client Setting, make sure that it points to the correct AX instance.

Do you use **Report Data Provider (RDP)** or **AX query** to load the data source?

Sometimes it helps to reboot the SSRS Service.

Also see: [.NET Business Connector Overview [AX 2012]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa659581.aspx)

Comment: I'm sure correct AX instance and I use Report Data Provider (RDP) load datasource. When I try to delete report on server after that restart AOS service and SSRS service the problem is solve. Thank you suggest.

Comment: That's what I learned over time in AX 2012, if you absolutely do not know what to do usually helps a restart or a complete passage x ++ compilation, synchronizing and CIL compilation.